# Perfomance issue with canvas in Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, canvas

I need to do some animated transformations with images using canvas.

Simple demonstration is in my fiddle, it's just a canvas, filled with pattern and rotated using requestAnimationFrame.

It works perfect in Chrome, but in Firefox it slows down, for what seems a rather simple task. It has 6-8 fps in FF instead of 50-60 in Chrome.

Firefox 38.0.5, Mac OS X 10.10

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/jyoggnjr/

```
context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(image, 'repeat');
update = function() {
  var date, offsetRotation;
  date = new Date();
  offsetRotation = ((Math.round(date / 10)) % 1000) / 1000 * (Math.PI * 2) - Math.PI;
  context.save();
  context.translate(radius, radius);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(0, 0, radius * 2, Math.PI, -Math.PI);
  context.closePath();
  context.rotate(offsetRotation);
  context.fill();
  context.restore();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I get 6 fps on chrome. So it's not an FF issue but a code issue. I will take a look.

Comment: I get rock solid 60fps in firefox, cyberfox, firefox developer 64bit from page load ... in chrome, when first started it fluctuated at 43-55 fps, then settled down to 60 eventually - so maybe it's not a code issue, perhaps a setting issue (hardware acceleration) - different browsers "blacklist" different hardware for acceleration too